# Setting different local address value in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Does anybody know is there's a possibility in Jsoup to set different local address?
Like in multi-hosted or clustered environment. Something like Apache HttpClient framework has

```
HttpClient.getHostConfiguration().setLocalAddress(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress))
```

Maybe that's something that is planned in future releases?
Thanks

Comment: In general, I think there's a possibility to set up local address with HttpClient, then get the InputStream with the same HttpClient and pass it to org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil. But I just wondered if that's possible using Jsoup only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks thats not possible (yet). The only accessable connection settings are in the [Connection](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html) class.

You get those settings via `connect()` method:

```
Connection c = Jsoup.connect("http://your.url.here");
```

Have a look into the sourcecode of the [HttpConnection](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html) (implements `Connection`).

If you have an inputstream from httpclient you can use it with jsoup since it has a [parse method for inputstreams](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jsoup.parser.Parser%29) (seems to be the best solution for now).

Btw. you can post feature requests here: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues